# How to log Oculus sensor data during playing a SteamVR game?

Tags: steam, oculus, virtual-reality

How is it possible, to get and log the data which is captured by the Oculus sensors during playing a SteamVR game with the Oculus hardware ? Is there any possibility ?

We aim to track the movements of a VR user during playing a game of steam.

Answer (score 0):

I want to provide the solution for my question.

After trying to find tools or work with frameworks like OpenVR, I decided to write a console application with the Oculus SDK.

- The best way to work with this SDK is to use the PDF version of it, which seems to be more completed.
- To get the console application and the SteamVR game run simultaneously without blocking, you have to start your application before you start the steam game (which then starts the SteamVR monitor too). This is very important, when the SteamVR monitor is running, even if there is no game open, the game will be blocked. Your application has to be started first, then it will work.